# Equivalent mass at barycenter in orbit

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, newtonian-gravity, orbital-motion, inertial-frames

I'm studying the two-body problem and while thinking of the Moon-Earth orbit I came across the following idea: What if the Earth disappeared and another body with mass $M$ appeared fixed at the barycenter of the Moon and Earth? What should be the value of $M$ such that the orbit of the moon stayed exactly the same?

By using this article as reference: [https://web.physics.ucsb.edu/~fratus/phys103/LN/TBP.pdf](https://web.physics.ucsb.edu/%7Efratus/phys103/LN/TBP.pdf), I derived that
$$M=\frac{m_E}{{m_M}^2}\mu^2$$
Where $m_E$ is the mass of the Earth, $m_M$ the mass of the Moon and $\mu$ the reduced mass of the Earth and Moon.

However, I have found nothing so far about this problem online, and I wanted to know if it's correct.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's correct. If you start with the equation of motion of the Moon
$$
m_M\ddot{\boldsymbol{r}}_M = - \frac{Gm_Mm_E}{|\boldsymbol{r}_M - \boldsymbol{r}_E|^3}\left(\boldsymbol{r}_M - \boldsymbol{r}_E\right),
$$
and you take the center of mass as the origin:
$$
m_M\boldsymbol{r}_M + m_E\boldsymbol{r}_E = \boldsymbol{0},
$$
then
$$
\boldsymbol{r}_M - \boldsymbol{r}_E = \frac{m_M+m_E}{m_E}\boldsymbol{r}_M,
$$
so that
$$
m_M\ddot{\boldsymbol{r}}_M = -Gm_Mm_E\left(\frac{m_E^3}{(m_M+m_E)^3r^3_M}\right)\left(\frac{m_M+m_E}{m_E}\boldsymbol{r}_M\right),
$$
which reduces to
$$
\ddot{\boldsymbol{r}}_M = -\frac{GM}{r^3_M}\boldsymbol{r}_M,
$$
with
$$
M = \frac{m_E^3}{(m_M+m_E)^2} = \frac{m_E}{m_M^2}\mu^2.
$$

Answer (score 0):

[image]

starting with two body system, Fig I, you have two equations:

$$r_{{{\it cm}}}={\frac {m_{{1}}r_{{1}}+m_{{2}}r_{{2}}}{m_{{1}}+m_{{2}}}
}=0
\\
r=r_{{2}}-r_{{1}}
$$

from here you obtain  that
$$r_1=-{\frac {m_{{2}}}{m_{{1}}+m_{{2}}}}\,r\\
r_2={\frac {m_{{1}}}{m_{{1}}+m_{{2}}}}\,r$$

your Ansatz: (Fig II) you put the Mass $~M~$ at the center of mass and ignoring the mass $~m_1$ at the position $~r_1$.

the equation of motions:

$$m_2\,\ddot r_2=-\frac{M\,m_2}{r_2^2}=-{\frac {m_{{2}}M \left( m_{{1}}+m_{{2}} \right) ^{2}}{{m_{{1}}}^{2}{r
}^{2}}}
$$

must equal to (your Ansatz)

$$m_2\,\ddot r_2=-\frac{m_1\,m_2}{r^2}$$

solving for $~M~$

$$M=\frac{m_1^3}{(m_1+m_2)^2}=\frac{m_1}{m_2^2}\,\mu^2$$

where $~\mu=\frac{m_1\,m_2}{m_1+m_2}$

hence your result is correct